# stopImmediatePropagation has different result in "document" and "p" element

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

When I use `stopImmediatePropagation` in `document`:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    console.log('bubble');
});

document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    console.log('capture');
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}, true);
```

when I click, the output is:

> capture

but when I use `stopImmediatePropagation` in `p` element:

```
document.querySelector('p').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    console.log('bubble');
});

document.querySelector('p').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    console.log('capture');
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}, true);
```

when I click "p" element in page, the output is:

> bubble
> capture

who can tell me why?

Comment: Just for clarity. The second code block (related to p elements) is not running **as well** as the first code block is it? If it is, its possible that one of the console traces is called from the `document` and one from the element event delegates.

Comment: I believe that has something to do with the three phases: capturing phase, target phase and bubbling phase. The event handlers you bound to the `p` element are executed in the "target phase", in which case `stop*Propagation` might not have any effect. I could be wrong though, I haven't found strong support for that claim: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events. If you add a `span` element inside the `p` element and click it, it works as expected. The `document` object is never in the target phase. When you click in an empty document, you are likely targeting the `body` element.

Comment: @FelixKling - IMHO you're onto something there... OP - You could achieve more clarity in testing if you attached both sets of event delegates with more unique output strings like "Capture P Element" "Capture Document" "Bubble..." etc etc

Comment: @leemo no ,the two code is separate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I already mentioned [in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24235687/stopimmediatepropagation-has-different-result-in-document-and-p-element/24249655#comment37430241_24235687), an event goes through three phases:

- **capturing phase** (*"The event object must propagate through the target's ancestors from the defaultView to the **target's parent**."*)
- **target phase** (*"The event object must arrive at the event object's event target."*)
- **bubbling phase** (*"The event object propagates through the target's ancestors in reverse order, **starting with the target's parent** and ending with the defaultView"*)

which are nicely visualized in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow):

[image]

The **target phase** seems to be new in the DOM Level 3 Event Specification, but it is what makes all the difference.

Since the `<p>` element is the target in the second case, both event handlers are executed in the target phase, not the capturing or bubbling phase. The specification says that event handlers are supposed to be executed in the order they have been bound. Since you bind the "bubbling" event handler first, it is executed first. Calling `stopImmediatePropagation` in the second event handler doesn't have any effect, since there are no additional handlers to be executed. That also explains, why the order of the output is

```
bubble
capture
```

And in fact, [if we log the `event.eventPhase` property instead](http://jsfiddle.net/7J9u6/1/), we get

```
2
2
```

where

```
interface Event {
    // PhaseType
    const unsigned short NONE = 0;
    const unsigned short CAPTURING_PHASE = 1;
    const unsigned short AT_TARGET = 2;
    const unsigned short BUBBLING_PHASE = 3;
    [...]
```

[If you change the order of the event handlers, it works as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/7J9u6/), but not because they are executed in different phases, but because the handler that calls `stopImmediatePropagation` is executed first.

---

It "works" when you bind the handler to `document`, because `document` is never the target of the event. When you click the empty document, the target is either the `<html>` or `<body>` element.

Comment: i agree the second case analysis, but the first case 'the target is most likely the <body> element' i dont't agree , please see : http://jsfiddle.net/7J9u6/3/

Comment: Yeah, I assumed it's either the `<body>` element or the `<html>` element. It seems to be the latter: http://jsfiddle.net/7J9u6/4/. Point is: `document` is not the target. Updated.